# Does the MCU offer any canonical information on the existence or non-existence of figures such as Santa Claus or the Easter Bunny?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

Within the canon of the MCU, including the movies, comic books, tie-in novels, and animated series, is there any canonical information regarding the existence, or non-existence, of mythical figures that are considered to be "fictional stories for children" in the real world such as Santa Claus, or the Easter Bunny.

Given that figures from mythology and religion canonically do exist, or canonically are fictional characters within the MCU?

For example, has the Easter bunny ever been shown to have a physical existence independent of the stories in popular culture in a similar way to Thor and Loki being physically real characters upon whom the Norse myths are based?

Conversely, has the Easter bunny been referenced as being a purely fictional character within the fictional setting of the MCU?

Answers citable to media only please, not supposition.

This is specifically NOT trivia, as it is relevant to the wider understanding regarding the MCU where characters from various cultures are explicitly real, either with their original origins intact or with modified origins — for example, Thor and Loki.

Comment: I could swear one of the later movies there is a scene with Tony Stark and his kid with a Christmas tree in the background.  If I'm remembering that correctly, then it can be assumed that the standard religious figures exist in the MCU.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Iron Man 3 is set at Christmas time, and there are numerous trees that can be seen. Including with Tony and the kid - not HIS kid, though. Hawkeye is set at Christmas time in NYC, so yeah, there is a kinda big tree at the Rockefeller Center, and more trees all over and there are Santas walking about; I mean, it's New York, at Christmas...  Iron Man 3 has a bunny, too, though no Easter Bunny....

Comment: That just means that they celebrate Christmas though

Comment: Which other mythological figures do exist and _are not_ superheores? Loki and co. are there because it's part of Thor's character universe. Why would Santa and easter bunny be real?

Comment: @Luciano, Do you know for a fact that the Easter Bunny ISN'T a super hero in the MCU, or are you just guessing because you don't personally remember reading about it in a comic? The MCU contains Spider Ham, Howard the Duck, and many other characters that may seem ridiculous to you.

Comment: Apparently, Santa Claus is canon in marvel in general (what isn't). But at the moment, I don't think we ever mention it as a real person in MCU.

Comment: @Luciano Why wouldn't they be real in the MCU? The Norse gods, the Greek gods, etc are all real in the MCU. Santa Claus and the Easter Bunny could very well be real in the MCU. They could also be fake. Hence the OP asking this question.

Comment: [Cross-post on Sci-Fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267578).

Comment: Saying your question is not trivia doesn't magically make it so. Santa Claus and especially the Easter Bunny are mutations or anomalies, far cries from the original folkloric origin. Why not ask if saint Nicholas, or any other saint for that matter, makes an appearance? The list of mythological and folkloric characters is so long, that I feel you really need to make an argument for your two choices.

Comment: No, but offering an explanation as to why it isn't trivia does. I limited it to these characters because the mods closed it when it was broader. If you don't have an answer please drag things off topic, save the chitchat for the chat forum.

Answer (score 4):

Santa Claus is referred to several times in *The Guardians of the Galaxy Holiday Special* and even makes an appearance (in the movie that Kevin Bacon is shown watching). In the special, the Guardians of the Galaxy and the people of Knowhere celebrate Christmas with Kevin Bacon.

Bzermikitokolok sings a song about Christmas (mostly describing Santa Claus) and asked Peter Quill (Star-Lord) what he thought about it.

> **Bzermikitokolok:** My bandmates and I have been mastering these old Earth instruments and working on a little ditty. And I thought you might be able to help us out as it's about one of your Earth traditions.
> [...]
> Everything I know about Christmas, I learned from Rocket, who learned from Cosmo,
> who learned from Kraglin, who learned from you. So I thought I might just take it back to the source and make sure I understand this all correctly. This is, after all, a historical document.

> **Bzermikitokolok** (*singing*)**:** One, two, three.
> Santa is a furry freak
> with epic superpowers
> He flies to every human home
> in under 14 hours
> He's a master burglar
> **Peter:** No.
> **Bzermikitokolok** (*singing*)**:** A pro at picking locks
> **Peter:** No.
> **Bzermikitokolok** (*singing*)**:** If you don't leave milk and cookies out
> He will put dung in your socks
> **Peter:** That is not part of the lore at all.

Peter's usage of the word "lore" to refer to the description of Santa Claus, suggests that Santa Claus is a mythical, fictional figure in the MCU, just like in real life.

Kevin Bacon is also shown watching *[Santa Claus Conquers the Martians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus_Conquers_the_Martians)*, a 1964 science fiction comedy film, in the scene before Drax and Mantis kidnap him. Santa Claus is shown in the scene that Kevin Bacon is watching. That movie, which features Santa Claus, being in the MCU further suggests that Santa Claus is fictional in the MCU, just like in real life.

[image: Santa Claus Conquers the Martians movie being watched by Kevin Bacon in The Guardians of the Galaxy Holiday Special]

---

On the Easter Bunny, while Easter has been mentioned in *The Guardians of the Galaxy Holiday Special*, the Easter Bunny is not referred to nor shown. Hopefully, the Easter Bunny will be referenced or make an appearance in a future MCU show. (Maybe in an Easter special?)